# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b

Tags: java, jruby

Does anyone know where this strange Java error comes from? It occurs in Jruby 1.7.8 (running on Java JDK 1.7.0_45 and using the [unlimited strength policy files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b
```

after or during installation with rvm

```
LoadError: load error: rubygems/security -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
      Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b
      require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1084
```

Comment: You're probably missing the javax crypto package on your classpath, which jruby/your app seems to expect.